# Is it possible to configure CruiseControl.net to display task exit codes in results?

Tags: ant, cruisecontrol.net

My company is developing a web application that builds in ant. I've been tasked with getting CruiseControl.net to differentiate between a build failure and a unit test failure, which it can't do natively. ( It currently lumps both together but doesn't help developers understand what's broken )

I have CC.net call a script that returns specific exit codes depending on the nature of an ant task failure. I'd like these exit codes to be reflected in the CC.net failure report / dashboard but am having some trouble finding resources on how this might be done.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Didn't know you could do ANT tasks in CC.NET.   Did you really mean ANT or were you thinking of nant.

Comment: Ant tasks aren't natively supported by cc.net but what you can do is call cmd and pass your ant command as arguments, or call a script that calls ant and arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly.  All the reports and display works from information in the logs which are XML files.  The display and reports work by applying XSLT to these XML files.

Take a look at your build logs and unit test logs,  to see if each of those process write the failure information to their respective log files.

If they do,  you should be able to write a custom XSLT or modify the existing XSLT to display that information.

Edit:

A different approach based on your comment.   You could probably redirect the ANT error code to a file.   Then you could have a seperate ccnet task that takes the error code from that file and re-format and display it (depending on how/where you want it displayed)